# Laravel AWS S3 Error

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I'm thinking I installed this wrong, but keep getting the same error. Installed `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`. S3 creds are setup in .env file.

Added these to the require in composer.

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php"
"aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0"
--------------------------------------------
```

Code:

```
$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$s3->put($location, file_get_contents($image), 'public');
```

Getting the following error:

```
exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Missing required client configuration options: 

' in /var/www/laravel/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/ClientResolver.php:328
```

Did some research online and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: If you resolved it please tell us how.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update :

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This: go into `config/filesystems.php` and eliminate any env that encompasses a value.

For example mine showed `'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),` 
so I changed it into `'cloud' => 'FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3',`

Do this to ALL values in this file, INCLUDING the S3 key, secret, region, and bucket. After that it should get you up and going.

I believe the issue is with Caching the values as Null rather than the actual edited values.